# Help needed in understanding an argument in proof in Section 3 Unit -5 of Galois Theory (Hungerford Algebra)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While self studying Galois Theory from Hungerford algebra, I have a question on Page 285 of textbook.

Its image:

[image]

[image]

> Kindly see last line of Image 2

It says axioms of Set theory guarantee that S is a set.

But I am having confusion in knowing which axioms exactly are used in proving S is a set as set theory wasn't even covered in any course.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the [axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), which states that the image of a set (here: $\operatorname{Im}\tau$) under a definable function (here: $\tau^{-1}$) is itself a set (here: $\mathcal{S}$).

If you don't know any set theory, there's little use in worrying about the details of this proof. Try to understand the idea and then take the Theorem for granted. Then, once you know some set theory, you can return to it.